# boost::python memory error with dynamic array and delete operator

Tags: python, c++, memory, boost, memory-management

I have this code that I'm using to test the speed of the C++ code vs. the original python code (I used a pointer array to make sure that the data is in a single continous block and because a vector has to make copies when it grows, which takes O(N) time):

```
void MyClass::test_packet(){
    time_t t1;
    time(&t1);
    PacketInfo* packets;
    for(int i = 0; i < 336000; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 18; j++){
            int N = 18;
            // allocate memory for 18 objects in a continous block
            packets = new PacketInfo[N];
            // create the packetInfo objects
            packets[i] = PacketInfo(i, i);
            // free the 18 memory blocks
            delete[] packets;
        }
    }

    time_t t2;
    time(&t2);
    cout << "total time for 336000 * 18 packets : " << (t2 - t1) << "seconds" << endl;
}
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MyClass)
{
    class_<MyClass>("MyClass", init< /*parameter types go here */>())
        // some other functions
        .def("test", &MyClass::test_packet);
}
```

the python test file looks like this:

```
from MyClass import *
MyClass.test()
```

this gave me a double free or corrupt memory error:

```
*** Error in `python3': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000016b1b10 ***
```

I commented the delete[] operator, but that gave me a segmentation fault:

```
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some incorrect code here

```
for(int i = 0; i < 336000; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 18; j++){
        int N = 18;
        // allocate memory for 18 objects in a continous block
        packets = new PacketInfo[N];
        // create the packetInfo objects
        packets[i] = PacketInfo(i, i);
```

If `i` is greater than 18 (which obviously it will be) then `packets[i]` will be an out of bounds array access.

The alternative with `packets[j]` doesn't make much more sense, since the allocation is positioned incorrectly with respect to the loop (presumably it should be before the loop).

Plus your statement about vectors is incorrect.

```
vector<PacketInfo> packets(18);
```

will allocate a vector of size 18, with 18 continuous elements, and since the vector is not growing no reallocation either.

Looking at your comments in the code I think the code you meant to write is

```
for(int i = 0; i < 336000; i++){
    int N = 18;
    // allocate memory for 18 objects in a continous block
    vector<PacketInfo> packets(N);
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        // create the packetInfo objects
        packets[i] = PacketInfo(i, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: so it was just a typo... thanks! btw for the vector, would the 18 objects be on the stack or the heap? If I remember correctly it needs to be a vector of pointers if I want the objects to be on the heap

Comment: The vector is on the stack, the PacketInfo objects are on the heap. That's true of the code above, it may or may not be true of a vector of pointers (since it would then depend on how you initialised the pointers).

Comment: Its exactly the same situation as with your version of the code, the pointer itself is on the stack, but what's its pointing at is on the heap.

Comment: well guess I gotta go back and read aboout memory allocation... thanks again!

Comment: Any time you declare a variable inside a function that variable is on the stack (static variables are an exception). This is true of any type of variable including pointers. The difference with pointers is that they also point at something, and that something may not be on the stack. The key to understanding pointers is to always keep separate in your mind the pointer and what the pointer is pointing at. They're not the same thing.